# Publication #: WO2014118527A1

Tags: expiration

Is this an active patent that was approved.  What company currently holds the rights to this patent for topical dantrolene?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Per the following link, this international application was denied entry into the European and German patent offices:
https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadoc?CC=WO&NR=2014118527A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=3&date=20140807&DB=&locale=en_EP

Per the following link, the UK application that this PCT claimed priority to has also been abandoned:
https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum/Case/ApplicationNumber/GB1301774.4

There do not appear to be any other applications in other offices or countries using this PCT as a priority.

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge, this isn't active patent. the legal status of this patent is   "Application deemed to be withdrawn". This patent is assigned by an individual(inventor). Further, this patent was claiming the priority from the provisional of GB. This might be due to GB provisional could not file an application. Thanks

Comment: Where do you get that status from? To me, it simply seems to have run its life without entering national phase: quite a different proposition. It also does not appear to have been assigned at all: the original inventor cannot assign it to themselves. Finally, the UK has not had provisional applications for 30ish years.

Comment: Hi Maca, thanks for the reviewing my answer. I think i have given the right details. 1) Legal status can be find out through the EP register which say  "The application is deemed to be withdrawn".  2) Yeah. it doesnt assigned to any applicant. there must be some legal issues as u mentioned " the original inventor cannot assign it to themselves". 3) UK has provisional application .Wipo claims the priority from GB201301774D0. Further , a link is attached which mentions about GB has provisional application. (Link: http://www.careeraddict.com/file-a-ppa-provisional-patent-application-in-the-uk) .

Comment: Link for legal status of Wipo:https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP14704623&tab=main

Comment: please let us know if there is some error. I m new toward the legal things. but i knew about patents.

Comment: The EP register you linked to gives the status of the automatic EP regional phase entry of the PCT, not the PCT itself. That is, the event occurs for any PCT application designating EP which does not formally enter EP regional phase, regardless of the status of the PCT itself.

Comment: The UK does **not** have provisional applications: they were abolished with the Patents Act 1977. You'll not find a single mention of them on the UKIPO site, for example. That careeraddict site is an untrustworthy content farm.

Comment: addition to that, the inventor has not filed the fee because non-establishment of opinion with regard to novelty , inventive step and industrial applicability and also due to reasoned statement under Rule 43bis.1(a)(i) with regard to novelty, inventive step and industrial applicability: citation and explanation supporting such statement.

Comment: WIPO: https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/docservicepdf_pct/id00000030121108/IPRP1/WO2014118527.pdf

Comment: Allow me to interfere here, since we had a "discussion" with ASHU VERMA in another topic. The UK document is not a provisional, it is a priority document: https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/docservicepdf_pct/id00000025883562/PDOC/WO2014118527.pdf           Provisional and priority docs serve similar purposes but they are not the exact same thing, because of different legal provisions.

Comment: and true, i could not find anything related to provisional in UKIPO site. but there are so many application having kind code. DO...can you explain which type of application it is.   (another carrer addict site:http://www.ukbusinessforums.co.uk/threads/how-to-convert-a-uk-provisional-patent-into-a-us-patent.174438/. can u look at once.)

Comment: yeah..i think Chempatent have given the perfect insights for that. they serve similar purpose but not provisional(might be)

Comment: Interesting forum. Read the last post of your thread, by SH and P. I think it answers your questions. Note that priority documents usually are (but are not limited to) patent application filings which may or may not end up being "full patent applications", to use the wording of the post.

Comment: @ASHUVERMA There is no D0 kind code used by the UKIPO. In fact, when the GB first filing was used for a priority claim, it did not have a kind code, since kind codes are only for publications.

Comment: I have searched another document so that i can clarify myself...please go through the link :http://cdn.mysipo.com/data/attachment/forum/201209/23/0118310q2hynlh7h28lnvn.jpg. This is image from the scientific literature "black sheep in the patent family" which mentions about GB patent with D0 kind code.